# Use JNA to call c from java crash VM,Could anyone tell me why this occurred?

Tags: java, c, jna

Use JNA to call c from java crash VM, Could anyone tell me why this ocuurred?
Where is wrong?

**c code:**

```
int Encode(char* systemId, char* account, char* userName, char* tradingPwd, char* expansion, char* ipAddress, char* userAgent, char * encryptedIn, int encrySize);
```

Compile c to shared lig libTestEncode.so in x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux machine
the Encode method just encode some string,and return it to java.

**java code:**

```
  public interface CLibrary extends Library {
    CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("TestEncode", CLibrary.class);
    int  Encode(String systemId,String account,String userName,String tradingPwd, String expansion, String ipAddress, String userAgent, byte[] encryptedIn, int encryptSize);      
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Properties p = new Properties();

    byte [] text = new byte[1024];
    int retCd  =CLibrary.INSTANCE.Encode("NRI","userID","username","password","","","",text, 1024);
    System.out.println(Native.toString(text));
    System.out.println("-----");
  }
```

Comment: You should use `byte[]` or `char[]` for *all* your sensitive information.  `String` can hang around in memory for a long time, effectively leaving your password exposed.  That's why most Java functions dealing with passwords use primitive arrays instead.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your posted code on my windows system and your usage of JNA is correct.
The problem is going to be in your C side code.  You should change your C code
to a do-nothing empty function that simply returns some value. You should no
longer see the JVM crash. Then inspect/debug your C code.